# Text Based User Interface to stdout

Tags: linux, text, command-line-interface, stdout, sox

I'm working on a headless device to play music, and I'm using Sox's `play` command to play the file.

I'm after a way to pipe the output formatted like this:

```
$play File.wav
```

> File.wav:
>
> File Size: 1.25M
>   Bit Rate: 64.0k 
>   Encoding: Unsigned PCM Channels:
>   1 @ 8-bit 
>   Samplerate: 8000Hz 
>   Replaygain: off 
>   Duration: 00:02:36.87
>   In:42.4% 00:01:06.56
>
> [00:01:30.31] Out:532k  [  -===|===-  ]        Clip:0

To be readable in a text file so it can be parsed by PHP and ouputted to the user.

I've tried the standard things like:

`$play File.wav >> output.txt`

which results in a file being created but an empty one, I don't need it to be realtime, just every few seconds, or even once per run just to check it's going ok.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sometimes it's better to cut your losses and pick a program with better output capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following (it would appear that sox outputs on STDERR):

```
play File.wav >> output.txt 2>&1
```

Whether it's going to be easy to parse is a different story ... :)

Namely the

```
[00:01:30.31] Out:532k [ -===|===- ] Clip:0
```

bit gets broken up over individual lines with your redirect.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for that, worked a treat, I don't really need to be able to parse the status bar, so I'll just remove that line.